# Adding 3ds max hotkey binding through kbdx file

Tags: 3dsmax, registerhotkey

Let's say that I've got a bunch of custom macros I've loaded into 3ds max and would like to assign hotkey bindings to them. I'd be able to do this programmatically in case I add more.

I start off with assigning "A" to a script I called "A":

[image]

This is what gets exported in the kbdx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ADSK_KBD>
    <shortcut fVirt="3" accleleratorKey="65" actionID="A`DragAndDrop" actionTableID="647394" />
</ADSK_KBD>
```

I add bindings for the next two:

[image]

This is what appears in the kbdx file, now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ADSK_KBD>
    <shortcut fVirt="3" accleleratorKey="65" actionID="A`DragAndDrop" actionTableID="647394" />
    <shortcut fVirt="19" accleleratorKey="65" actionID="AltA`DragAndDrop" actionTableID="647394" />
    <shortcut fVirt="19" accleleratorKey="66" actionID="AltB`DragAndDrop" actionTableID="647394" />
</ADSK_KBD>
```

There doesn't seem to be pattern and looks like the kbdx file is just a reflection of some internal 3DS Max datastore for hotkeys/bindings.

I've tried binding AltC by copying the last line and replacing 'AltB' with 'AltC'. AltC gets bound to Alt+B, which makes sense. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell Max I want to use "Alt+C" for the AltC action.

Is adding 3ds max hotkey bindings through this file possible? If so, how's it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be a way to tell Max I want to use "Alt+C" for the AltC action.

So, did you change the `accleleratorKey` value to 67, the ASCII code for `C`?

Comment: Cool! fVirt is related to hotkey 'pattern' (i.e. 3 for just a key like 'A', 19 for Alt+<key>, 11 for Ctrl+<something>, etc) and accleleratorKey is the keyboard key in ASCII.